# Can I change GNOME's lock screen back to the regular one?

Tags: gnome, lightdm, ubuntu-gnome, lock-screen, lock

GNOME used to lock using its standard locker, with the slide-up image and the password entry underneath that. For some reason, it has switched to a very primitive interface with my lock-image in the background and a basic, gray box in the middle containing my user icon and a password field - which, unfortunately, also has quite a bit of delay when opening my laptop lid before it shows and allows me to unlock my device.

I'm not sure exactly what caused my locker to change, but I have a few suspects:

- Switching from gdm to lightdm (I was on Ubuntu GNOME)
- Installing various desktop environments and WMs (e.g. KDE, Awesome, XFCE)

How do I make GNOME switch back to its standard UI? (Or, perhaps, switch to a different locker entirely, if possible - I know of another one I might prefer to use if possible.)

Comment: "Switching from gdm to lightdm" sounds like the culprit to me. Try switching back to `gdm`.

Comment: @pomsky Perhaps, but I'm a bit reluctant to switch back because gdm was so much slower to start. I'll give it a try and see what happens.